# Drive missing from Optimize Drives since upgrade to Windows 10 1803

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, raid, windows-10-v1803

Since upgrading Windows 10 (Pro) to version 1803, one of my drives is missing from the *Optimize Drives* list. The drive in question is, my D:-drive, a software-defined RAID-0 (striped) over two disks.

What is wrong with my drive, and how can I make it show up again? Or is this possibly a bug in Windows 10 version 1803?

[image: Optimize Drives]

The drive is present in Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]

Attempting to invoke `defrag` from the (administrator) command prompt does nothing:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>defrag D: /A
Microsoft Drive Optimizer
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In contrast, specifying a drive that doesn't exist yields error *"The given volume path is invalid. (0x89000001)"* (and usage instructions), and specifying one of the other existing drives does work.

I have looked at the event viewer, but I did not see anything that I could link to this problem.

Attempting to do this from PowerShell (run as administrator) results in:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter D -Analyze -Verbose
VERBOSE: Invoking analysis on Data (D:)...
Optimize-Volume : This volume cannot be optimized.
Activity ID: {8f3adaf8-67ea-4239-a659-1eec6745ec27}
At line:1 char:1
+ Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter D -Analyze -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Optimize-Volume], CimExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 43025,Optimize-Volume
```

When I list my drives in `diskpart`, one of the disk of this volume is listed with status Errors, and the volume as 'At Risk':

```
D:\>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.17134.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: RAMONA

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Errors          465 GB  1024 KB   *
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB  1024 KB   *
  Disk 2    Online          238 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online          931 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D   Data         NTFS   Stripe       931 GB  Healthy    At Risk
  Volume 1     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 2         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     C                NTFS   Partition    237 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 4     F   Elements     NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
```

I did a `select volume 0` followed by a `recover` in diskpart, which reverted the status back to *Online* and cleared the *At Risk* state, but the drive did not show up in *Optimize Drives* (not even after a reboot).

A subsequent execution of `chkdsk d: /f /x /r` results in a single bad sector being found (which is not recoverable, probably because it is a striped volume). This marks the disk back in *Errors* and the volume to *At Risk*.

I have ordered a new disk to replace this RAID-0 config, if this new disk does show up correctly, I will assume that the problem is indeed caused by this bad sector, although it is unclear to me why the diskpart recover (which cleared the error state) did not make the volume visible again. There must be something more to this.

Comment: Optimizing volumes on Dynamic Disks is probably meaningless because of the additional abstraction layer between physical drive and volume.

Comment: @DanielB You may be right (although I assume that reducing fragmentation has benefits even on a dynamic disk), but I'd still like to know why it is gone (instead of maybe displaying something like 'can't optimize drives due to error xyz'), similarly the powershell `Optimize-Volume` also doesn't provide any information about the problem.

Comment: The replacement disk (singular) does show up. So either it really was the bad sector causing the issues, or something about dynamic volumes.

Comment: @Daniel B Unless software raid is somehow different from hardware and hybrid raid in how it translates read and write operations then defragmenting is still meaningful.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Dynamic Disks is more than RAID. Depending on how it allocates physical storage to back logical volumes, there may be no meaningful relation between physical and logical data positions. Take a look at Linux LVM to get an idea about that.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I've got a Windows 2012 Server virtual machine running under VMware Workstation whereby the E: (data) drive is missing from optimisation. I'm trying to shrink the thin-provisioned disk (from 1.3TB to it's actually used space of ~800MB) and it refuses. The first step is to get it de-fragmented according to VMware instructions

Comment: @munrobasher Unfortunately not

Comment: Me neither! In the end I used CloneZilla to clone the disk to a new disk which shrunk it but it the cloned disk still doesn't appear in the list to optimise